# Trying to stop the new Row from resetting after refreshing site

Tags: javascript

I have created a table with HTML and JS where I will be able to add elements to the table. However, whenever I create a row in the table it resets and disappears AFTER I refresh the page, how do I prevent this?

```js
var list1 = [];
var list2 = [];
var list3 = [];
var list4 = [];
var list5 = [];
var list6 = [];
var list7 = [];
var list8 = [];

var n = 1;
var x = 0;

function AddRow() {

  var AddRown = document.getElementById('show');
  var NewRow = AddRown.insertRow(n);

  list1[x] = document.getElementById("kamp").value;
  list2[x] = document.getElementById("hjemmelag").value;
  list3[x] = document.getElementById("resultat").value;
  list4[x] = document.getElementById("bortelag").value;
  list5[x] = document.getElementById("gHjemme").value;
  list6[x] = document.getElementById("rHjemme").value;
  list7[x] = document.getElementById("gBorte").value;
  list8[x] = document.getElementById("rBorte").value;

  var cel1 = NewRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = NewRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = NewRow.insertCell(2);
  var cel4 = NewRow.insertCell(3);
  var cel5 = NewRow.insertCell(4);
  var cel6 = NewRow.insertCell(5);
  var cel7 = NewRow.insertCell(6);
  var cel8 = NewRow.insertCell(7);

  cel1.innerHTML = list1[x];
  cel2.innerHTML = list2[x];
  cel3.innerHTML = list3[x];
  cel4.innerHTML = list4[x];
  cel5.innerHTML = list5[x];
  cel6.innerHTML = list6[x];
  cel7.innerHTML = list7[x];
  cel8.innerHTML = list8[x];

  n++;
  x++;


  n.preventDefault();
  x.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<center>
  <table border="4">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Kamp nr:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="kamp" id="kamp"></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Hjemmelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="hjemmelag" id="hjemmelag"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Resultat</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="resultat" id="resultat"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Bortelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="bortelag" id="bortelag"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Gult kort hjemmelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="gHjemme" id="gHjemme"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rødt kort hjemmelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="rHjemme" id="rHjemme"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Gult kort bortelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="gBorte" id="gBorte"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rødt kort bortelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="rBorte" id="rBorte"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="btna">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table border="8" id="show">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Kamp nr</th>
        <th>Hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Resultat</th>
        <th>Bortelag</th>
        <th>Gult kort hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Rødt kort hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Gult kort hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Rødt kort hjemmelag</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</center>
```

Comment: Can you share your source upon which you're basing your implicit claim that changes made by JavaScript should be reflected in the source file on the server, or would otherwise be persisted by default? Would you expect any arbitrary JavaScript run in any client's developer console on any website to have this same effect?

Comment: I do not believe there is an easy solution for your problem.

Comment: As I said, I was wondering if it was possible. I didn´t mean to claim anything. I am a new beginner to coding in javascript and tried to see if it would be able to stay on the site, sorry if it was misleading

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a server, you and you alone can see the values if you do this:

NOTE: When you copy to your server, remove the comments and this

`[]; //`

Also note I moved the id to the tbody

```js
const AddRown = document.getElementById('show');
const list = []; // localStorage.getItem("list"); // get list from localStorage
// if (list) list = JSON.parse(list); // parse it into an array
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  list.push({
    kamp: document.getElementById("kamp").value,
    hjemmelag: document.getElementById("hjemmelag").value,
    resultat: document.getElementById("resultat").value,
    bortelag: document.getElementById("bortelag").value,
    gHjemme: document.getElementById("gHjemme").value,
    rHjemme: document.getElementById("rHjemme").value,
    gBorte: document.getElementById("gBorte").value,
    rBorte: document.getElementById("rBorte").value
  })

  // localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list)); // save list
  AddRown.innerHTML = list.map(item => `<tr>${
  Object.values(item).map(val => `<td>${val}</td>`).join("")
  }</tr>`).join("")

})
```

```html
<center>
  <table border="4">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Kamp nr:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="kamp" id="kamp"></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Hjemmelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="hjemmelag" id="hjemmelag"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Resultat</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="resultat" id="resultat"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Bortelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="bortelag" id="bortelag"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Gult kort hjemmelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="gHjemme" id="gHjemme"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rødt kort hjemmelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="rHjemme" id="rHjemme"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Gult kort bortelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="gBorte" id="gBorte"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rødt kort bortelag</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="rBorte" id="rBorte"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="btna">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="Add"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table border="8">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Kamp nr</th>
        <th>Hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Resultat</th>
        <th>Bortelag</th>
        <th>Gult kort hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Rødt kort hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Gult kort hjemmelag</th>
        <th>Rødt kort hjemmelag</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="show"></tbody>
  </table>
</center>
```